# PHP / MYSQL - display images from database issue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm making an e-commerce website, where i'm allowing a user to upload up to 3 images of the item that the user is willing to sell, the images are displayed in a caroussel and are stored in my database.

I'm using foreach php loop to display all the images in a caroussel, the problem is that, it's working only for the first image (normally displayed), and once i click on "next",  everything disapeers from the other items except the one i'm browsing.

[image]

```
if($total_row > 0)
{
    foreach( $result as $row ){
        $output .= '
    <div class="box product item">
            <div class="product__img">

        <div class="slideshow-container">
            <div class="mySlides ">
                <img class="product__img" src="images/'.$row["folder"].'/'.$row["image1"].'" style="width:100%">

            </div>
            <div class="mySlides ">
                <img class="product__img" src="images/'.$row["folder"].'/'.$row["image2"].'" style="width:100%">

            </div>
            <div class="mySlides ">
                <img class="product__img" src="images/'.$row["folder"].'/'.$row["image3"].'" style="width:100%">

            </div>


        <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
        <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

        </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product__details">
                <div class="product__details__title">
                    <h4>'.$row["name"].'</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="product__details__price">
                    <h3 " class="text-danger">'.intval($row["price"]).' دج' .'</h3>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="product__contact">
            <hr class="style11">
            <i class="far fa-envelope"></i>
            <input class="product__contact__btn" type="submit"   value="      Contacter vendeur"><br><br>
                    <input class="product__contact__comparateur" type="checkbox" name="comparateur" value="comparateur"> Ajouter au comparateur <br>
            </div>
    </div>
    ';
}
```

}

And this is the JS i'm using for the caroussel:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");

  if (n > slides.length) 
  {
    slideIndex = 1
  }  

  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = slides.length
  }

  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
}
```

DB:

[image]

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: It is more sensible to save your images in a folder and just store a url in your database that points to those image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that using carousel for each product items with different images requires unique id or class ("mySlides"), as it seems all of your product images are using same carousel class that is why clicking on one product next button is affecting the other products items also which are using same class for carousel, so try identifying the click on current item container only so it won't affect other products with same carousel class.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i''ll try that, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not storing 3 images into database kindly check that images are being store are not.Then try to store images through loop against every product.
I think this is the issue.
Hope so this will help you.

Comment: Actually i'm, can you expalin this part "Then try to store images through loop against every product." ?

Comment: First check that All images are uploading or not for each product?

Comment: They are, i can see them all when i browse my caroussel, but once i start browsing it disapeers from all the items except the one i'm browsing.

Comment: for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
Remove "none" and then try